# JaCoCo ant code coverage

Tags: junit, ant, jacoco

How do you fix this??

For the following line in my program JaCoCo shows:
"1 of 2 branches missed"

```
if(ia.length() < i+1){
```

Also for the following line i get: "1 of 4 branches missed"

```
if(ia.length() <= i+1 && ib.length() <= i+1){
```

the whole code:

```
public static int convertBits(int a, int b) {
      String ia = Integer.toBinaryString(a);
      String ib = Integer.toBinaryString(b);
      int s = 0;
      for(int i = 0;;i++){
        char a1 = '0';
        char a2 = '0';

        if(ia.length() < i+1){
          a1 = '0';
        }else{
          a1 = ia.charAt(ia.length() - i - 1);
          }
        if(ib.length() < i+1){
          a2 = '0';
        }else{
          a2 = ib.charAt(ib.length() - i - 1);
          }
        if(a1 != a2){
          s++;
        }
        if(ia.length() <= i+1 && ib.length() <= i+1){
          break;
        }
      }
```

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: @Godin how do you fix it

Comment: Write missing tests?

Comment: @ArtsArts and where is the test code against the above code?

Answer (score 2):

[JaCoCo is a code coverage tool](http://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/index.html) that generates [coverage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_coverage) report of your code  after its execution. Could be after manual execution, but typically after execution of tests, thus doing assistance in their creation.

Condition `if (ia.length() < i + 1) {` has two branches:

1. `ia.length() < i + 1 == false`
2. `ia.length() < i + 1 == true`

So

> 1 out of 2 branches

means that one of those branches was executed, while another was not.